# How do I specify multiple templateLoaderPaths for Freemarker in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, freemarker

I need to specify multiple template loader paths for FreeMarker in a Spring Boot web application but the [`FreeMarkerAutoConfigurationClass`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.1.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/freemarker/FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration.java) only let me specify one path using the [`spring.freemarker.templateLoaderPath`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) property, which uses the `setTemplateLoaderPath` method in the `FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory`. However, this class allows me to set multiple path using the `setTemplateLoaderPaths` method. Which is the best way to override this auto-configuration class and specify multiple loader paths? I don't really understand well the Spring Java config classes and I want an example for this before write the code I need. I'm using Spring Boot 1.1.2. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to provide your own bean of type `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer` with your desired configuration. To do so, add something similar to the following to one of your application's Java configuration classes:

```
@Bean
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer() {
    FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    configurer.setTemplateLoaderPaths("one", "two", "three");

    // Apply further configuration as needed

    return configurer;
}
```

**Update:** the latest Spring Boot 1.2 snapshots now accept a comma-separated list for the spring.freemarker.templateLoaderPath property allowing you to specify multiple paths without declaring a custom `FreeMarkerConfigurer` bean.

Comment: I believe the comma separated list of paths only works for the `templateLoaderPaths` property (note the "s" at the end), not for `templateLoaderPath`.

Comment: @ddekany The property is singular. Here's the setter for it: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/freemarker/FreeMarkerProperties.java#L81

Comment: You are right, it's `FreeMarkerConfigurer` that has both a singular and a plural property.